# How to make the print layout for a website print pdf?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, printing

I have a website with a print layout (using CSS media queries). I was wondering, is it possible to show (and print) a .pdf file in the print layout? I tried to use `<embed src="herf\to\my\location.pdf">` with `style="display: none;"` and then on the `@media print`:

```
embed {
    display: block;
}
```

but it didn't work.

Is it possible to use .pdf in a print layout?

If the solution involves javascript, please provide a vanilla js solution.

Comment: What problem are you attempting to solve by having a pf of your website print? Media queries are very powerful and the render engine can produce a very good print.

Comment: @BryceHowitson background  color doesnt work - you need to allow the browser to print bg color. Didn't find any way to do it.

Comment: I'd argue that printing background colors is a bad idea (waste ink, don't know the capabilities of the printer, not what users expect). But there are ways to do it. Here's an [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust) for webkit browsers.